# Get woocommerce catogry

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, list

Hello (sorry for bad english) i want know how can i get the category list in woocommerce . 
with this code i get wordpress category list

```
function gaga_lite_category_lists(){
    $categories = get_categories(
        array(
            'hide_empty' => 0,
            'exclude' => 1
        )
    );


$category_lists = array();
$category_lists[0] = __('Select Category', 'gaga-lite');
foreach($categories as $category) :
    $category_lists[$category->term_id] = $category->name;
endforeach;
return $category_lists;

}
```

i want replace it with woocommerce category to get woocommerce catogory please help me asap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not working because you didn't pass the Woocoomerce's Product category taxonomy.

By default `get_categories()` function will returns all terms data of default `category` taxonomy, if you did't mention specific taxonomy slug inside the arguments list. So, To retrieve the terms data of any specific taxonomy, We must have to pass the slug of that taxonomy.

Woocommerce uses `product_cat` custom taxonomy to store all Product's categories.

```
function gaga_lite_category_lists( ) {

     $categories = get_categories(

        array(
            'hide_empty' =>  0,
            //'exclude'  =>  1,
            'taxonomy'   =>  'product_cat' // mention taxonomy here. 
        )
     );


     $category_lists = array();

     $category_lists[0] = __( 'Select Category' , 'gaga-lite' );

     foreach( $categories as $category ){

          $category_lists[$category->term_id] = $category->name;
     } 

     return $category_lists;

}
```

Function reference [get_categories](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/)